# How can I see how much electricity a device connected via USB is drawing from my phone?

Tags: usb, charging, android-12, google-pixel-6

I have connected a device to my phone via an USB cable so that it receives some electricity from the phone. How can I see how much electricity a device connected via USB is drawing from my phone?

[image]

I use Android 12 with a Google Pixel 6

Comment: Related: [Is there a USB power consumption meter?](https://superuser.com/q/434354/149731)

Comment: The only possibility that comes to my mind is using an app that shows the current drawn from the battery. If you know how much the common battery usage in milliampere is without the connected USB device you can calculate the USB power usage.

Comment: @Robert thanks, "If you know how much the common battery usage in milliampere is without the connected USB device" yes that's the issue, it's a bit difficult to precisely estimate the consumption as it keeps varying depending on the activity of the the apps and the system.

Comment: I see two possibilities to make an estimation: If the battery usage monitor has a graphical plot over the last few minutes you should be able to "see" (in brain average calculation) an average value. So if you capture a few minutes before and after the USB device is connected you should be able to get an estimation. Best would be if the battery monitor app would calculate the average values for you for, e.g. for each of the last fiew minutes.

Answer (score 1):

For little money there are USB-Amperemeters. They measure the current [mA] that flows through them and also cummulate the energy, measured in milliampere-hours [mAh]. Just search for Usb Ampmeter or Usb Powermeter.

I don't know about your cabling, but probably you will need an adapter additionally, as the ones i know use standard size Usb Ports.